# Adding custom DTMF tones

Tags: android, call, data-stream, android-sound

So as far as I know there are 12 DTMF tones that you can send over a call (0-9,*,#). Now I wish to develop an app that can send DTMF tones in a set pattern. But I need more than 12 existing tones. So is there either

1. If there already exist more than tones that I mentioned above. So how to access them?
2. If not then if i can add my own custom tones?

Also as I said before I need to send them in a set pattern(e.g. When in a connected call if I press a floating icon it automatically sends tones for 1,5,7). So any suggestions on this is also welcome.